# How to find the number of subsets of a number with given list of numbers?

Tags: python, list, multiplication

I have this number which is a product of 2 prime numbers P and Q. Example

```
p=5
q=7
prod = int(p)*int(q)
#output: 35
```

and I have another set of numbers example:

```
num = [5, 49, 10, 27]
```

I Want to find the number of possible subsets that the product(P*Q) can have from the list of given numbers, example:

These subsets are (5,49),(5,49,10),(5,49,27),(5,49,10,27), (49,10),(49,10,27). There are 6 subsets, and the output is 6.

Comment: Aren't {5}, {4}, {10} and {27} subsets too?

Comment: What about (10, 27), or (49, 27)? Or are you asking specifically for numbers that can only be gotten by multiplying primes?

Answer (score 0):

While the wording in this question could be improved, from my understanding, you are trying to **find all subsets of the given list which contain the factors of prod**.  Here is the code I came up with:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from numpy import prod

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def factor_subsets(a, factors):
    return filter(lambda s: prod(s) % factors == 0 , a)

ps = powerset(set([5, 49, 10, 27]))
pq = 35

answer = factor_subsets(ps,pq)
print(answer)
print(len(answer))
```

Output:

```
[(49, 10), (49, 5), (49, 10, 27), (49, 10, 5), (49, 27, 5), (49, 10, 27, 5)]
6
```

Answer (score -1):

As its a known relation of maximum subsets to the length of the set, and you just want the number, not the actual pairings, we can keep it way faster.

I convert your input list to a set just to strip out any duplicates.

```
num = [5, 49, 10, 27]

subsetnumber = 1 # Always includes itself

subsetsin = set(num)
subsetlength = len(subsetsin)
for i in range(2, subsetlength):
    subsetnumber += subsetlength * (subsetlength-1) // i
print(subsetnumber)
```

this returns 11 unique subsets of 2 or more, for 1 or more, just change to "2" in range to "1",

edit: Thank you to the commenter below, forgot to count itself.